# Drag and Drop Feature in Video Converter App: Files and Folders Splitting into Individual Letters - tkinter

Tags: python, list, drag-and-drop

I am currently developing a Python video converter application and have encountered an issue related to the drag and drop feature. As part of this feature, I create a list of files that are intended for conversion. However, I've noticed that while some files and folders are added correctly, others are being split into individual letters. I'm unsure why this is occurring and would appreciate some clarification on this matter.

"

c

:

/

U..." instead of "c:/Users..."

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, Button, Listbox, END, filedialog
from tkinterdnd2 import *
import glob
import os

root = TkinterDnD.Tk()
root.title("Video Converter")
root.geometry("380x500")

file_list = []


def get_all_paths(event):
    """Get single file, multiple files or a folder path"""
    files = []
    if isinstance(event.data, str):
        if os.path.isdir(event.data):  # Handle a folder drop
            folder_path = event.data
            for file in glob.glob(f"{folder_path}/*.*"):
                attributes = os.stat(file).st_file_attributes
                if not os.path.basename(file).startswith('.') and attributes != 6 and not file.endswith(".ini"):
                    files.append(file)
        else:  # Handle a single or multiple file drop
            for file in event.data.split():
                print(file)
                files.append(file)
    for file in files:
        ListboxWidget.insert(END, file)
    return files


def update_listbox(event):
    """Update the file list."""
    file_list.extend(get_all_paths(event))
    if len(file_list) > 0:
        frame_1.pack_forget()
        frame_2.pack()
        frame_3.pack()


def clear_listbox():
    """Clear the file list."""
    ListboxWidget.delete(0, END)
    file_list.clear()


def folder_selection():
    """Choose destination folder."""
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory()
    return folder_selected


# Create widgets
frame_1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame_1.pack()

image = tk.PhotoImage(file='drop.png')  # Drag & Drop image
image_label = Label(frame_1, image=image, padx=5, pady=5)

frame_2 = tk.Frame()
ListboxWidget = Listbox(frame_2, width=100)

frame_3 = tk.Frame()
ClearButton = Button(frame_3, text="Clear", command=clear_listbox)
FolderButton = Button(frame_3, text="Destination", command=folder_selection)


# Place widgets
image_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="news", padx=5, pady=5)
ClearButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
FolderButton.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
ListboxWidget.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky="news", padx=5, pady=5)


# Drag & Drop binding
image_label.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
image_label.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", update_listbox)
ListboxWidget.drop_target_register(DND_ALL)
ListboxWidget.dnd_bind("<<Drop>>", update_listbox)

root.mainloop()
```

tried changing methods but can't get where I need to be